# IF Statments in EXCEL

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to calculate different price decreases when each statement is true for example

```
Statement 1 - Y
Statement 2 - N
Statement 3 - N
Statement 4 - N
```

I have been able to get it to work with one of the statements being true using

```
=IF(EXACT(L9,"Y"),I29-I9*C21,I29)
```

However, I don't know how I would be able to add that together if all 4 of the statements were Y as each of the statements is taking away different amounts of money if True.

My guess for it was

```
=IF(EXACT(L9,"Y"),I29-I9*C21,I29,IF(EXACT(L8,"Y"),I32-I8*C20,I32))
```

however, to many arguments were being made for the function

any help would be much apricated :)

---

This is what my excel document looks like at the moment. Don't think I did very well trying to explain it :/.

[Excel Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrpCy.png)

So more or less what I have been trying to do is when bought is changed to Y it would change that total however I've only been able to find out how to do it with one statement which has been changed to Y using:

`=IF(EXACT(J6,"Y"),H18-H6*I6,H18)`

sorry for the lack of being to explain much :/

Comment: Can you include an example of your excel file?

Comment: The too many arguments error is because the `if()` function only uses three arguments `=if(logical question, what to return when it is true, what to return when it is false)`. You seem to have added a fourth.

Comment: If you read the documentation for `IF`, it accepts three arguments: the condition to test, what to do if the condition is true, and what to do if the condition is false. It's unclear to me what you're actually trying to do, but you can't use `IF` the way you are to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can build more complex logical functions with IF statements.

If all four statements equal "Y"....

```
=if(and(A1="Y",B1="Y",C1="Y",D1="Y"),[Calculation if True],[Calculation if False])
```

So, here is an example of multiple tests nested in a statement.

Test 1:  Are all 4 cells equal to "Y"?

If yes, then "Test 1 equals True".

If not,

Test 2:  Are the first 3 cells equal to "Y" and the 4th cell equal "N"?

If yes, then "Test 2 equals True"

If not, "Neither Test 1 or Test 2 equal True"

This is the formula:

```
=if(and(A1="Y",B1="Y",C1="Y",D1="Y"),"Test 1 equals True",if(and(A1="Y",B1="Y",C1="Y",D1="N"),"Test 2 equals True","Neither Test 1 nor Test 2 equal True"))
```